# webix: Validating edits from datatable on the server

Tags: webix

I have the following scenario:

An datatable with some editable columns which validate for input on the client with the webix rules. There are columns though, that cannot be validated on the client, but on the server only (ie for unique id/code).

An approach would be to create a rule and validate with webix.ajax in synchronous mode that I would prefer to avoid this at all means.

I thought I could validate on 'save'. The server can return a status response with error or success. I can catch this with onAfterUpdate event of the datatable (correct me if there is a better way, but it works this way).
At this point, I would like to display a validation error on the datatable if the server script returns an error status and mark the row (and possibly the corresponding column/cell) with error.
I thought I could use the callEvent method on the datatable and fire a onValidationError event but I didn't manage to make that work.

```
save: {
  url: "save.php",
  autoupdate: true,
  on:{
    onAfterUpdate:function(response, id, details) {
      if (response.status == 'error')
        myDataTable.callEvent('onValidationError');
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation states that I can pass some parameters to the event from callEvent but I could not find any specification on the docs. The code above does not work (the event is not fired).

So the question is: How can I fire a onValidationError event for the datatable using callEvent?

or what would be another approach to use webix to show the error on the datatable with validation on the server side?

Thank you.

Comment: Have also tried to catch error status from server with onAfterSaveError but it does not fire with a status:"error" response from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calleing onValidationError event you can use

```
//mark cell, call after error response
myDataTable.addCellCss(id, columnId, "webix_invalid");
//remove mark, call after success response
myDataTable.removeRowCss(id, "webix_invalid");
```

which will mark the cell as non-valid.

On a side note, if you want to trigger some event with parameters, you can use code like next. Just beware that triggering an event is not a good way to change the component's state ( it can be used to trigger your own event handler though )

```
myDataTable.callEvent("event name", [param1, param2, param3])
```

just

Comment: Thanks @roman. Changing css on the row/cell does the trick.
I also tried the callEvent method that works though it does not change the state and does not mark the cell as error, so I'll stick to addCellCss/addRowCss.